# login with Oauth2 provider in twitter with satellizer

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I would like to build a login with satellizer for Twitter.
But I can't figure out how it is possible with the use of
Oauth2.0.

Here's my function:

```
$authProvider.twitter({
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
  scope: [],
  scopeDelimiter: ' ',
  type: '2.0',
  clientId: '[myClientID]'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a key here

`url: 'URL TO BACKEND SERVICE',`

Answer (score 0):

https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-started-with-oauth-2-0/2338

According to this post, twitter supports Oauth 2.0 for application-only authentications. User-based authentications must use Oauth 1.0 flow.

I also use Satellizer. It is pretty up to date and has a good twitter OAuth 1.0 implementation.